# Thread synchronization in C++, with less overhead

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

Consider the below code, this shall be a minimal sample of my question:

```
class TaskMgr {
public:
  // This is a threadsafe and lockfree queue implementation
  static concurrent_list_impl<std::string> Tasks;
  std::atomic<bool> mRun;
  std::atomic<bool> mStart;
    
public:
  TaskMgr() {mStart = mRun = false;}
  ~TaskMgr() {}
       
  void run() {
    mStart = true;
    while (!mEnd) {
        
        //PROCESS QUEUE TASKS
        std::string task;
        while (Tasks.try_dequeue(task)) {
            // DO STH WITH TASK
        }
        
        //FINISHING, CLOSING RESOURCES #1
        
        mEnd = true;        
    }
  }
};

TaskMgr tm;

void addTask(std::string task) {
    tm.Tasks.enqueue(task);
    if (tm.mEnd || !tm.mStart) boost::thread(boost::bind(&TaskMgr::run, tm)); #2
}

int main()
{
    addTask("TASK1"); //OK
    sleep(1);
    addTask("TASK2"); //Does not create new thread, because tm.mEnd == false && tm.mStart == true
    sleep(5);
    addTask("TASK3"); //OK, and manager will handle both TASK2 and TASK3
    sleep(15);
}
```

So I have a Task manager which handles `string` tasks. `Task` is a concurrent thread-safe and lock-free queue implementation, that shall reduces the locking and synchronization overhead.
But still, this example have at least one problem I see:

If *#2* checks the `mEnd` atomic just during the thread is executing the *#1: colsing resources*, `mEnd` is still `false`, and `mStart` is `true`, so a new thread will not be created, and "TASK2" will only be handled once a new item is added which actually triggers the thread creation.

I don't want a thread to constantly running, tasks frequency is low, but I also don't want to lose tasks, and if possible try to keep overhead as low as possible.

Comment: The standard way to approach this is for the task dispatcher to wait on a condition variable when the queue is empty.  When a thread pushes a task onto an empty queue, it should signal the condition variable.  C++11 adds support for these threading primitives, so you can use `std::condition_variable` (and of course `std::mutex`).  Or you can use Boost instead, of course, which is pretty much what caused these things to be adopted into the C++ standard.

Comment: Note that since you're using a lockfree queue, you may not know for certain whether the queue is empty or not when pushing.  So you can just signal the condition variable every time.  Yes, you still have a mutex for the dispatcher, but none of the threads enqueuing tasks need to deal with that.  Just signal and continue.

Comment: I'll further note that since task frequency is low, it seems like premature optimization to be going for any kind of lock-free implementation.  The whole point of lock-free stuff is for high-frequency and low-latency tasks in critical applications such as real-time audio.

Comment: Yes, indeed I've done high-frequency stuff with this queue and it proved its advantages over other non-lock-free ones. I know condition_variables, yes, my idea here was to make the  thread *on-demand*, run it only when needed.

Comment: Do you say having a thread which mostly waits on a condition_variable is better (less overhead, less CPU, memory, etc) than recreating one smartly on-demand?

Comment: Yes, in general.  Definitely creating a thread is higher overhead than switching to a running thread.  That's why we generally avoid creating threads when possible (preferably using thread pools or similar).  Having a thread created does take a small amount of memory (for the thread's process state, stack, etc) but in your case, the thread will simply be sitting in a wait state until the condition variable is signalled.  Spurious signals are relatively rare, so the thread will almost always only wake up when you want it to.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to combine these different ideas into a kind of hybrid approach, but it might not be the best way to go.  Essentially you're making a thread pool that can grow dynamically.  But you set no limit on the number of threads.  You might consider allowing your thread pool to grow to some size determined by the number of logical processors available, but no larger.  You might also consider allowing threads that have been idle for some period of time to exit.  You _probably_ don't need a lock-free queue.

Comment: Yes, with condition_variables lock-free queue seems unnecessary and then it also won't add overhead. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `boost::thread(boost::bind(&TaskMgr::run, tm))` is overly complex. Well, maybe; I haven't looked at Boost recently, but I doubt that it's less powerful than `std::thread` here. `std::thread` knows how to bind arguments, so all you need is `std::thread(&TaskMgr::run, tm)`.